# When I type sbi(caps lock off), I am getting result of both if statement and else statement. How can get only result of if statement?

Tags: java

This is my scenario: Bank is a class that provides functionality to get rate of interest. However, rate of interest varies according to banks. For example, SBI, ICICI and AXIS banks could provide 8%, 7% and 9% as a rate of interest.

```
    class bank{
        public String name;
        int interest(){
            return 0;
            }
            String name(){
                name = "bank";
                return name;
            }
            }
    //SBI Bank
            class SBI extends bank {
                int interest() {
                    return 8;
                }

                public String name() {
                    String name;
                    name = "SBI";
                    return name;
                }
            }
    //ICICI Bank
            class ICICI extends bank {
                int interest() {
                    return 7;
                }

                String name() {
                    String name;
                    name = "ICICI";
                    return name;
                }
            }
    //Axis Bank

            class AXIS extends bank {
                int interest() {
                    return 9;
                }

                String name() {
                    String name;
                    name = "AXIS";``
                    return name;
                }
            }


    /*Main Class*/
                public class head {
                    public static void main(String args[]) {



                        String n;
                        SBI s = new SBI();
                        ICICI i = new ICICI();
                        AXIS a = new AXIS();

                        System.out.println("Enter the bank name");

                        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
                        n = sc.next();

    /*Conditional Statements*/

                        if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(s.name())) {
                            System.out.println("SBI rate of Interest is " + s.interest());

                        }
                        if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(i.name())) {
                            System.out.println("ICICI rate of Interest is " + i.interest());
                        }
                        if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(a.name())) {
                            System.out.println("AXIS rate of Interest is " + a.interest());
                        } 
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                            System.out.println("Enter SBI , ICICI or AXIS");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger or on paper. Look at your conditionals, and how they relate to each other-or don't relate to each other when they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several serious problems here. The one that is troubling you right now is that you don't use `else if` between your `if` statements that are supposed to be mutually exclusive. Fixing that would solve your immediate problem.

But the `name` field of the subclasses is never set. It will be `null`, unless at some point you manage to call the `name()` method of the `bank` base class. That method sets the field to `"bank"`.

To be clear, the subclasses are not setting the `name` field because in the `name()` method you have a local variable `name` which shadows the field.

```
public String name() {
    String name;   // this local variable shadows the "name" field
    name = "SBI";  // this sets the local variable; the field remains null
    return name;
}
```

One way you could end up calling the `name()` method of the base class is:

```
bank b = new SBI();
System.out.println(b);
```

Even though it's an `SBI` objects, it calls the method of the base class because the variable is declared to be a `bank`, not an `SBI`.

This will print `bank` and now the `name` field of that `SBI` object will be set to `"bank"`, although if you call its `name()` method, it will still return `"SBI"`. But if you access its `name` field, you'll see it's `"name"`:

```
System.out.println(b.name());
System.out.println(b.name);
```

This will print `SBI` and then `name`. This is a recipe for disaster. Finally, I will just note that the `name` field is `public` which can lead to further problems, and you are not following the normal Java naming convention that class names start with an upper case letter, fields and variables start with a lower case letter, and constants are in all caps. In particular, class `bank` should be named `Bank`. Not following standard naming conventions makes your code harder for other programmers to read and makes it less likely that you'll get help here with your program.

You need to rethink your design. The field should either be `protected` and set in the constructor, or you should get rid of the field and just return a constant from the `name()` method, at which point `Bank` could just be an interface with `name()` and `interest()` methods instead of a class. (Or return the name from the `toString()` method, and make `Bank` a functional interface (an interface with just one abstract method.)) Finally, you need to use `else if` for a chain of mutually exclusive if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning the print statement in else because that else is for the last if conditional statement ONLY,  that's

```
if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(a.name()))
```

It is executing the else block because SBI does not equal a.name

To fix that. You should do this

```
if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(s.name())) {
                        System.out.println("SBI rate of Interest is " + s.interest());

                    }else 
                    if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(i.name())) {
                        System.out.println("ICICI rate of Interest is " + i.interest());
                    }else 
                    if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(a.name())) {
                        System.out.println("AXIS rate of Interest is " + a.interest());
                    } 
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                        System.out.println("Enter SBI , ICICI or AXIS");
                    }
```

Although this will solve your problem, I will advice you use switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

USe Else IF  Condition and Remembr to Make Vehicle class Abstract

```
 abstract class bank{
       public String name;
       abstract int interest();
       abstract String name();

        }
//SBI Bank
        class SBI extends bank {
            int interest() {
                return 8;
            }

            public String name() {
                String name;
                name = "SBI";
                return name;
            }
        }
//ICICI Bank
        class ICICI extends bank {
            int interest() {
                return 7;
            }

            String name() {
                String name;
                name = "ICICI";
                return name;
            }
        }
//Axis Bank

        class AXIS extends bank {
            int interest() {
                return 9;
            }

            String name() {
                String name;
                name = "AXIS";
                return name;
            }
        }


/*Main Class*/
            public class Demo {
                public static void main(String args[]) {



                    String n;
                    SBI s = new SBI();
                    ICICI i = new ICICI();
                    AXIS a = new AXIS();

                    System.out.println("Enter the bank name");

                    java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
                    n = sc.next();

/*Conditional Statements*/

                    if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(s.name())) {
                        System.out.println("SBI rate of Interest is " + s.interest());

                    }
                    else if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(i.name())) {
                        System.out.println("ICICI rate of Interest is " + i.interest());
                    }
                    else if (n.equalsIgnoreCase(a.name())) {
                        System.out.println("AXIS rate of Interest is " + a.interest());
                    } 
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                        System.out.println("Enter SBI , ICICI or AXIS");
                    }
                }
            }
```